# NullReference Exception when assigning to a Class Integer[]

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I want to be able to transfer values from one DataGridView in Form1 to another DataGridView in Form3. To do this I've chosen to filter them in 3 different variables which would be in classes so that i could access them later in Form3.

These are the classes: (I've had them as a single one with 3 variables already)

```
public class verify1
{
    public static int[] CodUser { get; set; }
}

public class verify2
{
    public static DateTime[] DataFim{ get; set; }
}

public class verify3
{
    public static string[] Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Altho, when i am assigning values to the variables i get a NullReferenceException right in the first time the for runs.

This is the code i used to assign values:

```
int a = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
{    
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);   
    if (date <= DateTime.Now)   
    {   
        verify1.CodUser[a] = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue);    
        verify2.DataFim[a] = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FormattedValue);
        verify3.Nome[a] = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);   
        a++;   
    }
}
```

Now, what i don't understand is why Visual Studio says the value is null. The exception happens in the following line:

```
verify1.CodUser[a] =   Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue);
```

(which is 17389) in the first place and won't let me go further. I cant see why it's returning null. By the way, the DataGridView is fully fulfilled with data.

Why is it returning null?

Comment: The null refers to theverify1.CodUser (and company) that have never been initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto-properties are automatically intialized to **default value** of the returning type. 
You are dealing with *reference type* `Array`. The **defalt value** for the *reference type* is `null`.

It's better, in this case, avoid to have auto properties, but use ordinary ones.

Example:

```
public class verify1
{
    static List<int> codUser = new List<int>(); //definition
    public static List<int> CodUser
    { 
       get { return codUser;} 
       set {codUser = value;} 
     }
}
```

I esplicitly used a `List<T>` in this case, cause in moment of declaration you don't know the excat size of array, and alsoo, according to the code provided, it can vary.

**EDIT**

Can use it like this (in practice like you did before)

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
{    
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);   
    if (date <= DateTime.Now)   
    {   
        verify1.CodUser[a].Add( Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue));    
        ......
        ....  
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I only want it to return code user in a condition so i am supposed to enter this inside the if ? Thanks mate.

Comment: @BrunoCharters: this is actually the verify1 class definition. What if condition you're talking about?

Comment: Hey, can i have all 3 CodUser, DataFim, Nome, in the same class then?

Comment: @BrunoCharters: sure, you can.

Comment: where to i set variable type ? I see CodUser is Int but where is it defined? Cause DataFim must be DateTime or String. Thanks

edit: i see where now (:

Comment: It is giving me ArgumentOutofRangeException Tigran. Right in the first one, the int one you posted.

Comment: Yeah i tried it but i won't allow me to use an index "[a]" before it. Does it add indexes as 0,1,2... for the list?

Comment: Actually, it works with just add but then it doesn't really creat a list. It creates an empty list except for the last element of it. Which means only the last item of, let's say CodUser list had content in it. Tried `CodUser.Insert(a,string); aswell, same result it seems mate.

Comment: Error was in the form3 code when populating the cells. Sorry and thanks everyone for the help. And thanks for the speed of the answears too. Is there a way to rep you?

Answer (score 4):

You have the public properties defined in your `verify1` class, but you never initialize them. They're null.

You need to initialize the arrays before you use them:

```
int a = 0;
int rowCount = dataGridView1.RowCount;
verify1.CodUser = new int[rowCount];
verify2.DataFim = new DateTime[rowCount];
verify3.Nome = new string[rowCount];
```

You might also want to take another look at how to use classes properly. I'm guessing you don't need three separate classes each with a single static property. It looks like you should have a single `VerifyInfo` class with three fields. You can then store those in a `List<T>`:

```
public class VerifyInfo
{
    public int CodUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataFim { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

And then your loop code would be much cleaner:

```
var verifyInfos = new List<VerifyInfo>();

for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    var date = Convert.ToDateTime(
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);

    if(date <= DateTime.Now)
    {
        verifyInfos.Add(new VerifyInfo
        {
            CodUser = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value),
            DataFim = Convert.ToDateTime(
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FormattedValue),
            Nome = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value)
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: But what i'm assigning to is verify1.CodUser, right? I want CodUser to save a value. Or i have to do something like verify1.CodUser = 0; ?

Comment: @BrunoCharters - No. You have CodUser defined as an array. You need to initialize the array before adding values.

Comment: Thanks alot, the exception is gone. Altho when i call uppon it on the next form,
`    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < Form1.verify1.CodUser.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Form1.verify1.CodUser;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = Form1.verify2.DataFim;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = Form1.verify3.Nome;                
            }`

it returns only 1 row. Shall i use a command to add new rows each time for runs? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't verify1.CodUser null? How do you create it?

EDIT:

I've editted my answer to reply to Bruno's comment. You have to initialize your arrays first to be able to use them. To make a simple test, please create a separate project, paste these two lines, run your project in debug mode and set the breakpoint after array2 is created:

Int32[] array1;
Int32[] array2 = new Int32[3];

What do you see in the first array? It is null because it wasn't initialized. All you have to do is to initialize your arrays as I did with array2.

Hope this helps,
Piotr

*sorry for formatting, stackoverflow javascript is somehow blocked for me.

Comment: Verify1 is the class i use to call upon the variables so i can use them in another form. I've used this before but not as an array.

Comment: I understand why it was returning null. Very clear answear. Can't rep otherwise i would (: